# C: linked lists confusion

Tags: c, pointers, struct

error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
The problem line is "gl->point[0] = (struct list *)&foo;"
I read somewhere that I could be storing a declaration. If that is the case I need that explained to me.

```
struct ref {  
    char **name;
    struct list **point;
};

int main ( ) {   
    typedef struct {
        char **name;
        struct list **point;
    } temp;  

    struct ref *gl;  

    gl->name = malloc ( 1024 * sizeof(char *) );  
    gl->name[0] = "A";  

    temp foo;  
    foo.name = malloc ( 1024 * sizeof(char *) );  
    foo.name[0] = "B";  

    gl->point[0] = (struct list *)&foo;   

    printf ( "!%s!\n" , gl->point[0]->name[0] );  
}
```

Comment: Note that the typedef temp and the struct ref types are not the 'same type'; you should not repeat code like that.

Comment: Oh, I mistook all structs to be the same type. that helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's `struct list`? There is no type named `struct list` (at least in what you've shown).

Maybe you meant `struct ref`?

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in the code sample are you defining **struct list** which is what the error is.